# How do I join fields in MongoDB?

Tags: linux, database, bash, mongodb

I am working with a large dataset in MongoDB which has the following structure:

```
{ "_id" : "00-872@rambler.ru", " pass" : "00-87", "field4" : 872, "field5" : 123456, "pass2" : "00-872", "pass3" : "00-8721" }
```

As you can see, it's a total mess.

I am looking to to rearrange the entire collection so it just has two fields (_id and pass). However, to do so, I need to join all the additional values in the other fields and place them all under the second field.

So in this case, the following:

```
"field4" : 872, "field5" : 123456, "pass2" : "00-872", "pass3" : "00-8721"
```

can be located under 'pass'.

For example:

```
{ "_id" : "00-872@rambler.ru", " pass" : "00-87",  "872",  "123456",  "00-872", "000-8721" )
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

I want to keep the existing value in the pass field also.

MongoDB version 3.4.10.

Comment: What is your mongodb version  and add the complete expected output ?

Comment: @Veeram See thread, sorry!

Comment: Np. Cant tell from your output . So just need pass to be a array of values or comma delimited string ?

Comment: @Veeram In the first example, there are multiple fields inside the relevant collection. I wish to join all the additional data into the 'pass' field and remove the outstanding fields.

Comment: join can mean multiple things like `pass:{"pass":"00-87",  "field4" : 872, "field5" : 123456, "pass2" : "00-872", "pass3" : "00-8721"}` or `pass:["00-87",872,123456, "00-872", "000-8721"]` So which one do you like.

Comment: @Veeram The second one is what I mean.

Comment: Try `db.collection_name.aggregate([{"$project":{
      "pass":["$pass", "$field4", "$field5", "$pass2", "$pass3"]
    }}, { $out : "collection_name" }])`. This will overwrite the existing collection  with new data. You can use bulk write option as well similar concept but you can control what you write.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DBRefs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs) to store references between documents.

> MongoDB does not support joins. In MongoDB some data is denormalized,
>   or stored with related data in documents to remove the need for joins.
>   However, in some cases it makes sense to store related information in
>   separate documents, typically in different collections or databases.
>
> MongoDB applications use one of two methods for relating documents:
>
> - Manual references where you save the _id field of one document in    another document as a reference. Then your application can run a
>     second query to return the related data. These references are simple
>     and sufficient for most use cases.
> - DBRefs are references from one document to another using the value of    the first document’s _id field, collection name, and,
>     optionally, its    database name. By including these names, DBRefs
>     allow documents    located in multiple collections to be more easily
>     linked with    documents from a single collection.
>        To resolve DBRefs, your application must perform additional queries    to return the referenced documents. Many drivers have
>     helper methods    that form the query for the DBRef automatically. The
>     drivers [1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs) do    not automatically resolve DBRefs into documents.
>        DBRefs provide a common format and type to represent relationships    among documents. The DBRef format also provides
>     common semantics for    representing links between documents if your
>     database must interact    with multiple frameworks and tools.

More info at: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/